# how to detect installation of new software in our system using java (solution must be OS independent)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

i want to monitor each and every installation of software so that i can put restriction on some malfunctioning software from being installed automatically.

Solution should be able to work on each any every OS. So is there any library or jar to do the same?

Comment: I doubt this is possible to do, the differences between OS are so huge...

Comment: @nogard: at the prior phase if we can monitor this on a single OS then it's also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

There are significant differences between OS-es, but, I think, there's a workaround to help you to solve this task.

Make an application that is [watching a directory for changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

In your application, use

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

to determine the operating system. And for every operating system monitor a predefined set of directories/folders related for the recognized operating system.

Comment: it work for directory monitoring for sure but i want to monitor specifically installation and uninstall process only..so any suggestion for that?

Comment: Due to big differences between os-es, I think it is not possible to monitor running processes via universal approach. But if you monitor a directory, where the OS locates installed applications, then your application can determine the moment when a new application is being installed or uninstalled.

Comment: @ Rafael Osipov: ok got it buddy. thnx to help